# Counting the number of items in a list matching criteria, jinja/flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm passing a list of dictionaries into my HTML with Flask

```
data = [
{'name':'val1', 'status':0},
{'name':'val2', 'status':1},
{'name':'val3', 'status':1}
]
```

It's accessed in the HTML via the variable `data` as well `data=data`

I can count the number of items in `data` in the HTML with

```
{{ data|length }} # 3
```

But I want a length of items that have a certain status. ie 1

```
{{ length of data where item ['status] == 1 }}

# should out put length of 2
```

**This question is not a duplicate. This question specifically asks how to filter based on a criteria. The other answer only filters based on boolean.**

if my 'status' key can hold any values `'apple', 10, 'xyz'` I want to be able to filter base don that not a True of False.

**ANSWER**

```
FLASK
database = [
{'name':'val1', 'status':'abc'},
{'name':'val2', 'status':'xyz'},
{'name':'val3', 'status':'xyz'}
]

HTML
{{ database|selectattr('status', 'equalto', 'xyz') | list | length}}

# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will solve the problem, loop through the data and maintain count value for it;

```
{% for row in data %}
    {% if (row.get('status')|int = 1) %}
        {% set counter = counter + 1 %}        
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```